# Line breaks in JQuery Datatables cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm populating a datatables cell via Ajax and JSON. To get line breaks in a list of names in a a cell I've tried \n and escaped \n (\\n). Neither work.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post some sample code?

Comment: The data inside the cell is probably rendered as HTML, which means you need `<br/>`, not just `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is because your cell is HTML so \n ,not being a valid HTML markup, is not causing a line break. 
A `<br/>` element will likely cause a link break in your case, however without sample code from you it is hard to know.

Comment: the content of the cell is not in html and doesn't show up on a show source

Comment: View source only shows the page as it was sent down by the server (i.e. before any javascript has run). To debug AJAX requests you'll need to use the browser's developer tools. F12 brings them up in IE or Ctrl+Shift+I in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Ok thanks I was looking in web Developer/view source but didn't realize that firebug does show content. The new line doesn't show up: <td class="">Manny SMALL Kevin SMITH Tom McNEAL Amaresh AMID </td>

Comment: \n is not valid HTML markup so it won't cause a link break, that is why it is not displaying.

Comment: @user1840253 backslash n is not valid HTML markup, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp for information on the HTML line break markup.

Comment: @user1840253 Stevebot is correct: Your output format is HTML, so you need to use `<br>` instead of `\n` or `\\n`.

Comment: Yes in the process of testing that (was thinking that this was happening in js).